# Django rest framework sending a string with single quotes back instead of JSON with double quotes

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am sending JSON via POST to a view. The response I get back is only part JSON and the rest has changed from double quotes to single quotes.

My question is how to I make sure that I am sending all this back as JSON in a get? As an added bonus to my problem, I don't know what fields will be sent to leasee.

The POST looks like:

```
{"leasee":
{"profession":{"permanentMakeup":true,"esthetician":true,"hairStylist":true},
"compare":{"uniqueVsChic":"56"},
"name":"dfasdfasdf",
"contact":{"text":true,"facebook":true}}}
```

But GET gives me:

```
{"leasee":
"{'compare': {'uniqueVsChic': '56'}, 
'profession': {'hairStylist':True, 
'esthetician': True, 
'permanentMakeup': True}, 
'name':'dfasdfasdf', 
'contact':{'facebook': True,'text': True}}",
"created_at":"2015-05-22T23:27:13.598686Z",
"updated_at":"2015-05-22T23:27:13.609893Z"}
```

my views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from sitepages.models import SalonSubmission, StylistSubmission
from sitepages.serializers import SalonSerializer, StylistSerializer
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.dispatch import receiver


class SalonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SalonSubmission.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = SalonSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        post_save.send(sender=self.__class__, name=instance.business_name, phone=instance.phone)
        return super(SalonViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)


class StylistViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = StylistSubmission.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    serializer_class = StylistSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        instance = serializer.save()
        post_save.send(sender=self.__class__, stylist=instance.leasee)
        return super(StylistViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)


@receiver(post_save, sender=SalonViewSet)
def send_email(sender, **kwargs):
    send_mail(kwargs['name'], kwargs['phone'], 'from@example.com',
              ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)


@receiver(post_save, sender=StylistViewSet)
def send_email(sender, **kwargs):
    send_mail('aName', kwargs['stylist'], 'from@example.com',
              ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

My serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from sitepages.models import SalonSubmission, StylistSubmission


class SalonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SalonSubmission

        fields = ('business_name', 'phone', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')


class StylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StylistSubmission
        fields = (
            'leasee',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at'
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created_at', 'updated_at')
```

My models.py:

from django.db import models

```
class SalonSubmission(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class StylistSubmission(models.Model):
    leasee = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="/media/")

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `leasee = models.CharField(max_length=2000)` is a charfield. So Django is simply returning the string stored in this field. Also it is not storing valid JSON string neither because JSON only allows double quote.

```
{'compare': {'uniqueVsChic': '56'}, 
'profession': {'hairStylist':True, 
'esthetician': True, 
'permanentMakeup': True}, 
'name':'dfasdfasdf', 
'contact':{'facebook': True,'text': True}}
```

looks like stringified `dict`.
So you can try to parse `leasee` as a `dict` in your serializer.